# How do I get orderly responses from modem with pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I need to read a lot of the lines the modem sends me. I already have 2 instances of "read looping", but I'm suffering to find a way to name an important data that is coming as 'x'.

```
while lido is not True:

        q = ser.readline()
        w = q.rstrip()
        e = w.decode('utf-8')
        if (e == 'SBDRING'):
            print ('Ring Alert recebido')
            lido = True
            ser.write(str.encode('AT+SBDIX\r'))
            time.sleep(10)
            ser.write(str.encode('AT+SBDRT\r'))
            time.sleep(2)
            u = ser.readline()
            i = u.rstrip()
            o = i.decode('utf-8')
            print(o)
            popupmsg(o)
```

I want "o" (u,i) to be the response of "ser.write(str.encode('AT+SBDRT\r')). This is the command to read the message that is in my modem buffer, but doing so I'm getting o = AT+SBDIX.

Any insights?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems unlikely that your code is mysteriously changing what you expect to get into something different, so by Occam’s Razor, let’s assume that the most likely reason is that the modem is in fact sending AT+SBDIX. Suggest you confirm this by checking the communication using a terminal program, in fact there is one built into pyserial.

Comment: I'm sending AT+SBDIX to the modem, it's necessary to start a session to retrieve the message inside its buffer. The thing is that "ser.readline()" is showing that it reads even these commands I'm sending to the modem, not only the response.

Comment: Don’t modems usually echo what you send them, I think they do, so your code will have to handle that. Try sending the commands using a serial terminal emulator/program ensuring that local echo is turned off and confirm what is received. Then write your code to handle the same.